# Elastic APM agent is inactive due to configuration. What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have a problem when I want to start the app, when i type `npm run server`. And the error information are like this :

```
opbeans@1.0.0 server /home/rahmat/independentProject/sample/sample3/opbeannode server.js

Elastic APM agent is inactive due to configuration
server is listening on port 3001

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

Elastic APM agent is inactive due to configuration, what does it mean?

Maybe someone can help me, please...

This is the package.json :

> {
>     "name": "opbeans",
>     "version": "1.0.0",
>     "description": "The Opbeans inventory management system",
>     "main": "server.js",
>     "dependencies": {
>          "after-all-results": "^2.0.0",
>          "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
>          "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
>          "detect-port": "^1.2.2",
>          "elastic-apm-node": "^1.3.0",
>          "express": "^4.14.0",
>          "pg": "^6.1.2",
>          "redis": "^2.6.3",
>          "request": "^2.79.0",
>          "webpack": "^4.3.0",
>          "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1",
>          "workload": "^2.3.0"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>          "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
>          "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.0",
>          "react-scripts": "^1.1.1",
>          "standard": "^10.0.2"
>     },
>     "scripts": {
>          "db-setup": "./db/setup.sh",
>          "test": "standard *.js server/**/***.js db//*.js",
>          "server": "node server.js",
>          "client": "npm run start --prefix client/",
>          "client-build": "npm run build --prefix client/",
>          "client-install": "npm install --prefix client/",
>          "postinstall": "./client/build-client.sh",
>          "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run    client\"",
>          "workload": "workload -f .workload.js"
>     }

Comment: what result do you get when you run `npm start`?

Comment: can you provide `package.json`

Comment: This is the package.json :